# Javascript ES5/ES6 classes and error handling

Tags: javascript, sentry, mobx-react

Say I have a class like this

```
class SomeUIComponentDataStore {
    async function getUser() {
         try { //do something that can fail}
         catch(e) { 
           // gracefully fail, setting portion of ui to fail state
           Sentry.captureException(e); // report to some metrics service
         } 
    } 
}
```

I repeat that pattern for every async function. Where on failure I respond to the error, and then report it to some service (in this case that service is Sentry).

Is there anyway I can create a BaseClass, that will automatically decorate my catch statement with Sentry.caputreException(). Or do i have to manually write it each time a I see an error.

Comment: I typically add additional logging to my sentry calls so I have more data in the error since the exceptions are useless. You can define some sort of function, but you are basically writing the same thing, just skipping what you re copy and pasting.

Comment: The error messages I get are actually pretty useful. So I dont mind just logging the raw error.

In my case most of them are coming from firebase apis

Answer (score 2):

You could define a decorator to reuse that logic and decorate methods that can throw:

```
function catchError(target, name, descriptor) {
  const original = descriptor.value;
  if (typeof original === 'function') {
    descriptor.value = function(...args) {
      try {
        return original.apply(this, args);
      } catch (e) {
        Sentry.captureException(e); // report to some metrics service
      }
    }
  }
}

function catchErrorAsync(target, name, descriptor) {
  const original = descriptor.value;
  if (typeof original === 'function') {
    descriptor.value = async function(...args) {
      try {
        return await original.apply(this, args);
      } catch (e) {
        Sentry.captureException(e); // report to some metrics service
      }
    }
  }
}

class SomeUIComponentDataStore {
  @catchErrorAsync
  async getUser() {
    //do something that can fail
  }

  @catchError
  otherMethod() {
    //do something that can fail
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ohh this seems perfect actually.

Comment: Actually I run into an issue

Comment: Actually I run into an issue

say I have this code: 


https://gist.github.com/lemiesz/3bf6397716cdc4a3fe04b9fe509bb46a

catchError decorator no longer handles my exception that is being thrown up from the try, catch block

Comment: I updated the answer to handle the async case, does it work ?

Comment: Dont have time to try it out yet... but looks good. Thanks for helping. Will get back to you later today

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base class with the `Sentry.captureException(e);`, and then have overrideable functions for the custom try/catch functionality.

```
class BaseClass {
  function onGetUser() {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented");
  }

  function onGetUserFail() {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented");
  }

  async function getUser() {
    try {
      onGetUser();
    } catch (e) {
      onGetUserFail();
      Sentry.captureException(e);
    }
  }
}

class SomeUIComponentDataStore extends BaseClass {
  function onGetUser() {
    // do something
  }

  function onGetUserFail() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really what I am looking for. What I want is an extensible class that catches any error, and reports it. Without knowing the function signatures ahead of time.